# Почему программа не видит данные блочного атрибута 'text'?

Tags: python, парсер, xmlparser, node-html-parser

Пишу парсер для `flashscore` на `Python`. Не видит внутри блочного тега атрибут `text` (То есть не выводит данные). Пишу код `jupyter notebook`.

Вот мой код:

```
year= '2023'
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from collections import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(f'https://www.flashscore.com/volleyball/')
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.execute_script("windowsscrollTo(0, documentbody.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.event__more.event__more--static').click()
    except:
        break
match_id = driver.find_elements(by='css selector', value='.event__match.event__match--last.event__match--twoLine')
len (match_id)
match_id[0]
matches_id = [el.get_attribute('id') for el in match_id]
matches_id
matches_id = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('g_12_', ''), matches_id))
matches_id
game = matches_id[0]
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/match' + game + '/#match-summary-summary/match-summary'
driver.get(url)
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.smh__part  smh__home smh__part--1')
result = [0].text
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4532\3043893053.py in <module>
----> 1 result = [0].text
```

Сообщение об ошибке:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Вот скриншот ошибки:

[image: Вот как выглядит блочный тег в devtool]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь получить текст элемента, используя метод .text у списка result = [0], который не имеет атрибута text.

Должно быть что-то вроде

```
year= '2023'
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from collections import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random as rd

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(f'https://www.flashscore.com/volleyball/')
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.execute_script("windowsscrollTo(0, documentbody.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.event__more.event__more--static').click()
    except:
        break
match_id = driver.find_elements(by='css selector', value='.event__match.event__match--last.event__match--twoLine')
len(match_id)
match_id[0]
matches_id = [el.get_attribute('id') for el in match_id]
matches_id = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('g_12_', ''), matches_id))
game = matches_id[0]
url = 'https://www.flashscore.com/match' + game + '/#match-summary-summary/match-summary'
driver.get(url)
result = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.smh__part  smh__home smh__part--1')
result = result[0].text
```

Конкретно изменена строка result = [0].text на result = result[0].text

Comment: Теперь ошибка другая IndexError: list index out of range.Помогите пожалуйста. Неделю мучаюсь. Как вы написали до этого тоже пробовал. Как будто в блочном теге нету информации. А она есть и атрибут как раз text (проверил)